# More than 1 Facebook user Ids

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

there are more more than one Facebook user ids.

1. returned by the Graph API
2. which [findmyfbid.com](http://findmyfbid.com/) returns

My questions are:

1. why are there two different ids
2. can we get one of them if we have the other

thanks

Answer (score 1):

findmyfbid.com returns the "global/real ID" by scraping the profile, which is not allowed. You should not use that ID anyway and there is no serious/allowed way to get it.

The Graph API returns an "App Scoped ID" that is unique in the App, after authorizing the user. You will get a new one for the user in another App. Only use the App Scoped ID.